# Integral of $(4\cot^{3}x+\cot^{2}x+\cot x-2)e^{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate the following expression
$$(4\cot^{3}x+\cot^{2}x+\cot x-2)e^{x}dx$$

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what sort of things you've tried, or where you're stuck? If there's other background for *why* you're integrating this, that may also be helpful. (If it's just an exercise, obviously that's not needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are going to integrate it by parts one by one in descending order.

$$
\begin{aligned}
4\int e^x \cot ^3 x & =4 \int e^x\left(\csc^2 x-1\right) \cot x d x \\
& =-2 \int e^x d\left(\cot ^2 x\right)-4 \int e^x \cot x d x \\
& =-2 e^x \cot ^2 x+2 \int e^x \cot ^2 xdx-4 \int e^x \cot xdx
\end{aligned}
$$

---

$$
I=-2 e^x \cot ^2 x+3 \int e^x \cot ^2 x d x-3 \int e^x \cot x d x-2 e^x
$$

---

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int e^x \cot ^2 x d x & =\int e^x\left(\csc ^2 x-1\right) d x \\
& =-\int e^x d(\cot x)-e^x \\
& =-e^x \cot x+\int e^x \cot x d x-e^x
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Plugging back yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\boxed{I =-e^x\left(2 \cot ^2 x+3 \cot x+5\right)+C}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Congratlulations !

Comment: Suddenly solve it after thinking for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this integral can't expressed as closed form. If you can use hypergeometric function, you can integrate since the following equality holds.

$$
\int\cot xe^xdx=-ie^x{}_2F_1\left(-\frac i2,1;1-\frac i2;e^{2ix}\right)-\left(\frac25+\frac i5\right)e^{(1+2i)x}{}_2F_1\left(1,1-\frac i2;2-\frac i2;e^{2ix}\right)+\mathit{Const.}
$$

This identity can be easily obtained by expressing cot as an exponential function.

Comment: You could make it simpler using the Appell hypergeometric function of two arguments.$$\int \cot^n(x)\,e^x\,dx=(-i)^n e^x F_1\left(-\frac{i}{2};-n,n;1-\frac{i}{2};-e^{2 i x},e^{2 i x}\right)$$

Comment: or use the [Lerch transcendent](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/05/0025/) for a result with simpler functions